# Classes cannot be accessed from outside the package

Tags: java, android, barcode-scanner

I'm making an android application for a RadioPad : barcode scanner working on Android and I have a problem in recieving the barcode information.

***The problem is that some classes cannot be accessed from outside the package.***

Another problem with Constants.

The RadioPad I'm working on is `Zebra MC3200` working on Android 4.1 and Upper.

I'm working on this library : `barcode_scanner_library_v2.4.6.0`

This is the Main Activity.java file I'm working on :

```
package com.example.zebrascanner;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.SyncStateContract.*;
import android.view.View;

import com.zebra.scannercontrol.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IDcsSdkApiDelegate {


SDKHandler sdkHandler;

int scannerId;

ArrayList<DCSScannerInfo> mScannerInfoList = new ArrayList<>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




    sdkHandler = new SDKHandler(this);
    sdkHandler.dcssdkSetDelegate(this);
    sdkHandler.dcssdkSetOperationalMode(DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_MODE.DCSSDK_OPMODE_SNAPI);

    int notifications_mask = 0;

    // We would like to subscribe to all scanner available/not-available events
    notifications_mask |=
            DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_EVENT.DCSSDK_EVENT_SCANNER_APPEARANCE.value |
                    DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_EVENT.DCSSDK_EVENT_SCANNER_DISAPPEARANCE.value;

    // We would like to subscribe to all scanner connection events
    notifications_mask |=
            DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_EVENT.DCSSDK_EVENT_SESSION_ESTABLISHMENT.value |
                    DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_EVENT.DCSSDK_EVENT_SESSION_TERMINATION.value;

    // We would like to subscribe to all barcode events
    notifications_mask |= DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_EVENT.DCSSDK_EVENT_BARCODE.value;

    // subscribe to events set in notification mask
    sdkHandler.dcssdkSubsribeForEvents(notifications_mask);


    // enable scanner detection
    sdkHandler.dcssdkEnableAvailableScannersDetection(true);


    //Synchronisation

    sdkHandler.dcssdkGetAvailableScannersList(mScannerInfoList);
    sdkHandler.dcssdkGetActiveScannersList(mScannerInfoList);

}




//CONNECTION TO SCANNER


public void connectToScanner(View view) {
    new MyAsyncTask(scannerId).execute();
}

private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {
    private int scannerId;

    public MyAsyncTask(int scannerId) {
        this.scannerId = scannerId;
    }


    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_RESULT result =
                DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_RESULT.DCSSDK_RESULT_FAILURE;
        if (sdkHandler != null) {
            result =
                    sdkHandler.dcssdkEstablishCommunicationSession(scannerId);
        }
        if (result == DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_RESULT.DCSSDK_RESULT_SUCCESS) {
            return true;
        } else if (result == DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_RESULT.DCSSDK_RESULT_FAILURE) {
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
}




//RECEPTION


public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IDcsSdkApiDelegate {

    @Override
    public void dcssdkEventBarcode(byte[] barcodeData, int barcodeType, int fromScannerID) {
        Barcode barcode = new Barcode(barcodeData,barcodeType,fromScannerID);
        dataHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.BARCODE_RECIEVED,barcode).sendToTarget();
    }
```

The main problem is actually here :

//RECEPTION

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IDcsSdkApiDelegate {

    @Override
    public void dcssdkEventBarcode(byte[] barcodeData, int barcodeType, int fromScannerID) {
        Barcode barcode = new Barcode(barcodeData,barcodeType,fromScannerID);
        dataHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.BARCODE_RECIEVED,barcode).sendToTarget();
    }
```

I expect to import import com.zebra.scannercontrol.Barcode from the package but the error was that it is not public and cannot be accessed from outside the package.

Comment: Yes, because only public classed can accessed from outside. I am sure that This class property is exposed by some public classes or interface. Kindly check the documents.

Comment: @MohammadMisbah Thank you for your answer, but how can I check the documents ? I may not be able to modify the library.

Comment: Yes you can't change library code. Check the library document which is provided by them i.e. How to use their methods.